# How can i catch errors only if there is an error?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

Axios catch an error even if the response is `success`.

I tried to check the error but in my opignion, it doesn't make sense.

Is there something wrong in the code in my vuex acion:

```
export const store = ({ dispatch, state, commit }, { payload, context }) => {
    return axios.post('/api/projects', payload).then((response) => {
        commit('addProject', response.data)
        commit('setProjectData', response.data)
    }).catch(function (error) {
        if (error)
        context.errors = error.response.data.errors
    })
}

//Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'error.response.data')
```

Comment: The error says that `error.response.data` property is undefined, so why are you trying to get `.errors` property of undefined? It doesn't have such property. Run `console.log(error)` inside the catch and make sure it has the properties you are trying to get

Comment: Sorry, it was an error of mine. I had an error in the axios function. Therefore, there was no error from the response but the function was in mode error